# My gulp iconfont renders like an ugly live traced icon

Tags: css, svg, gulp, icons, glyphicons

I noticed my icons look off when I zoom in to my navigation. I'm using Gulp-iconfont (npm package) with just the default template and styling as in the link is described.

My HTML:

```
<li class="pageNav_metaItem">
 <a href="#" class="pageNav_metaLink"><i id="open-apps-bar" class="icon-apps"></i></a>
</li>
```

[Rendered font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOPB.png)
[.svg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtwKL.png).

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: it seems that your source icons are not correct. Please check an test with different SVG icons

Comment: ^thanks @sato this actually was the problem. I ran trough all icons and there were a few without an fixed size. This made the icon font rendering incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

As [I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apOPB.png), all your icons don't feel well. To fix it add the `fontHeight` setting to the `gulp-iconfont` configuration:

```
// ...
.pipe(require('gulp-iconfont')({
    fontName: 'icons',
    formats: ['eot', 'woff', 'woff2'],
    fontHeight: 1024
}))
// ...
```